# Canceling a Cosmos DB NoSQL query when it is too slow

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

My application uses the Cosmos DB .NET client to execute document count queries of the form
`SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c WHERE ...`
where the condition may vary dynamically (i.e., they are a function of the user input). Some queries are very slow to execute (e.g. due to expensive `regexmatch` constraints), and in such cases I want to either cancel them prematurely (e.g. after a configurable interval) or prevent them from executing in the first place. What is the best way to achieve this?

1. Is there a way to estimate the RU without fully executing the query?
2. If not, is there a way to cancel the query server-side when a certain time has elapsed or a specified RU-threshold will be exceeded?
3. Or can I use a `CancellationToken` with a timeout to ensure that on timeout, fewer RUs will be consumed than when the query would run to completion?

Comment: RU cost has nothing to do with time; it's about query complexity, filtering, indexing, projection, etc. You can estimate RU by running the query once and seeing RU cost (it should remain relatively the same, assuming the schema, indexes, and query stay the same). You also don't have to follow a continuation token. There is no server-side cancel. Also, "slow to execute" isn't quantifiable. Might be good to edit your question to provide specifics. As written, it's impossible to tell what might cause your query cost/time to be larger than expected.

Comment: @DavidMakogon But RU cost correlates with time because of throttling, so that would be a metric that I could use for determining whether to execute the query or not. I cannot run the query beforehand because queries can take on infinitely many forms. For any particular query I know why it runs slowly, the question is how to detect it without fully running the query.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I asked a separate question regarding server-side cancellation here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77128786/689923. Would be great if you could clarify this as it is not clearly documented.

Comment: Just remember that a query that results in throttling is still completed (but your next query will be throttled until you pay off your "RU debt"). Maybe a future iteration (via continuation token) is now slower due to having to wait for debt payoff (e.g. throttle time) but that's not a "slow query" - that's a function of not enough RU/sec allocation.