# Server-side cancellation in Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Many methods in the Cosmos DB .NET client take a `CancellationToken` parameter to allow cancellation of a request (e.g. `FeedIterator.ReadAsync()`). From the source code it is apparent that the token is checked at various points in the code, but it is also eventually sent along to the HTTP endpoint of the Cosmos DB.

If the cancellation token is cancelled during the phase when the client is waiting for data from the HTTP endpoint (e.g. in `GateStoreClient.InvokeClientAsync()`, the HTTP request is cancelled. Does this also cause the Cosmos DB to prematurely stop the computation and consume fewer RUs (e.g. when it is stopped after a few milliseconds even though it would otherwise run for a few minutes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

CancellationTokens are a .NET specific construct, they cannot be sent to the service.

Having said that, the [service quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-request-limits) mention that the processing time for a request is up to 5 seconds.

In .NET, CancellationToken is use along with RequestTimeout: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-dotnet-sdk-request-timeout?tabs=cpu-new#customize-the-timeout-on-the-azure-cosmos-db-net-sdk

CancellationToken is not checked while the request is on the wire (that's what RequestTimeout is for) but in-between retries (that's why the docs say that the CancellationToken time should always be larger than RequestTimeout).

So even if you set the CancellationToken to 1 second, the network request is not stopped at 1 second, it will run either until it receives a response or the RequestTimeout is elapsed.

EDIT: CancellationTokens are also checked in-between pages of a Query operation. In a nutshell, checked in-between network requests (either because they are retries or next pages).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that link. Just a few more comments: Yes, `CancellationToken` is .NET specific, but if used with `HttpClient`, it results in an aborted request, which the server can detect and react upon. Secondly, I checked the source code, and the user's `CancellationToken` is ultimately linked with a new token that expires at RequestTimeout. That means the HTTP request is aborted before RequestTimeout if the user's `CancellationToken` is set to be cancelled before RequestTimeout. So my question is really about what the server does when the HTTP request is aborted.

Comment: I have not seen a place where the user CancellationToken is linked with RequestTimeout in the source code. Also, we do not wire the user CancellationToken into the HttpClient call. As far as I am aware, the server does not act on the client cancelling the request. If the request timesout on the client, it can still complete processing on the server.

Comment: See `CosmosHttpClientCore.SendHttpHelperAsync`. The user's token is fed through and ultimately ends up here. This method creates a linked cancellation token source and configures it with `cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(requestTimeout)`. This linked token is then fed through to the `HttpClient`.

Comment: You are right, but this would only apply to Gateway Mode clients. For Direct Mode (default), CosmosHttpClientCore is only used for metadata operations outside of the user direct control (so no passing CT from public surface).